# How to use Play WS with SSL?

Tags: java, rest, playframework-2.3

My Java client application needs to do REST calls. I was instructed to use Play's WS implementation. Currently, I have this:

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
NingWSClient wsc = new play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build());
WSRequestHolder holder = wsc.url("http://www.simpleweb.org/");
```

This works. However, my application needs to access a secure web service that uses SSL. I have a PKCS12 cert for my client. How can I get WS to use this certificate to establish a secure connection?

To be clear, this isn't a Play application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible directly with WS. [Play docs says](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS) : "WS does not support client certificates (aka mutual TLS / MTLS / client authentication). You should set the SSLContext directly in an instance of [AsyncHttpClientConfig](http://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig.html) and set up the appropriate KeyStore and TrustStore."

You could do something like this maybe:

```
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
        .getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("YOUR.p12");

keyStore.load(inputStream, "Your password as char[]");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "Your password as char[]");

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null,new SecureRandom());
AsyncHttpClientConfig httpClientConfig = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(httpClientConfig);
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured this out yesterday, and it does indeed work.

Comment: The Play docs you linked are over a year old. Play WS does support client certificates in 2.3.x.

Comment: It is possible in Play 2.3, which OP is using.

Comment: I'm not the fastest to update in Scala/Play world due to backward compatability issue. But please don't hesitate to edit my answer and add additional information for more recent versions. The answer is going to be helpful then for whichever version of Play you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the parser.  See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/KeyStores for details about the configuration.

```
val config = play.api.Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseString("""
                              |trustManager = {
                              |  stores = [
                              |    { type: "pkcs12", path: "/path/to/pkcs12/file", password: "foo" }
                              |  ]
                              |}
                            """.stripMargin))
val parser = new DefaultSSLConfigParser(config, app.classloader)
val sslConfig = parser.parse()

val clientConfig = new DefaultWSClientConfig(sslConfig = sslConfig)
val secureDefaults = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder(clientConfig).build()
val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(secureDefaults)
val wsc = new play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build());
val holder = wsc.url("http://www.simpleweb.org/");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have added your Certificate to your trust-store like
   this:

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore
>   {JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts -noprompt -alias 
>   -file {CORRECT_PATH}/what_ever.crt

2. If still the problem exists, set the path directly by setting java parameters in your execution command line like this:

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore={JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts