# Setting SSLContext for AsyncHttpClient - Can not read keystore file

Tags: rest, playframework, ssl-certificate

I need to use a AsyncHttpClient in my play application to make POST() call on https protocol. I am using play 2.2.x version.
I tried @Esfand's code mentioned in below question's first answer but it is failing for java.io.FileNotFoundException.

[How to use Play WS with SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726968/how-to-use-play-ws-with-ssl)

Here is what I did : 
1) I used keytool command to generate keyStore on my C drive .. something like this

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mypublickey -file "" -keystore  "c:\mypublicstore.jks”

It stores file on C drive with name  mypublicstore.jks" (note the double quotes at the end)

2) Then I am using following code to read that

```
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\mypublicstore.jks\"");
    String certPass = Play.application().configuration().getString("certificate.password");
    keyStore.load(inputStream, certPass.toCharArray());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, certPass.toCharArray());


    But it is failing at line 3 of the code. It can not find the file on the system. I tried reading another file on the same location and it works fine then why it can not read jks" type of file? Am I doing something wrong here?
```

In FileInputStream I should give keystore path or certificate path?
        Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that AHC can not be used with play 2.2.x version. I need to upgrade to 2.3.x version.